# How do I replace a audio gutenberg block to native audio wordpress

Tags: block-editor, audio

I am developing a blog theme, I would like to change the output of the audio gutenberg block to native wordpress. Any hint

Gutenbergs output: 
`<audio controls="" src="http://photer/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/salamisound-1020034-brushing-with-a-toothbrush-4.mp3"></audio>`,[image]

I would like to deduce how the WordPress widget does it,
like wp_audio_shortcode.
[image]

thanks to everyone who answers I will be glad of any help